# Build Specific Apps on the Wordpress Framework?

Tags: framework

I'm planning to use wordpress as a backend for theming and user registration/login features.
I'm creating an app using php which I'd like to work within a wordpress site.
I don't know how to build wordpress plugin but I want to use it as a backend.
Any idea how it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Just [learn how to create WordPress plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin), and you can add pretty much any functionality you want.